# gdx-testing example test not running

Tags: java, junit, libgdx, junit4

Using libGDX, and TomGrill's gdx-testing's tests subproject, and trying to run with gradle (`gradlew tests:test`) the default example from the examples directory and I get this error.

```
Testing started at 14:47 ...
14:47:05: Executing task 'test'...

Executing tasks: [test]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 0s
14:47:06: Task execution finished 'test'.
```

If I try to run it with IntelliJ's run-tests button [image]
I get the error

```
Process finished with exit code 1
Class not found: "de.tomgrill.gdxtesting.examples.AssetExistsExampleTest"Empty test suite.
```

And last, if I try to run only one test from said suite I get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was with Gradle versions. I updated to the newest version of Android Gradle Google provides, and used a newer local Gradle as that was needed, and for some reason, this doesn't work. Made a new empty project and left the original Gradle versions, and the tests ran. There might be a better way to fix this, however, I'm going to go with this.